# How to write a shipping rule for wordpress woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom shipping rule which is based on subtotal order. if the subtotal is 75$ cost then it should be the following. how to write a rule or use a plugin for this.

I am using wordpress woocommerce. i have tried many different plugins, like flexible shipping, table rate shipping, weight based shipping.

```
US States:

Orders under $75.00
Standard shipping $5.99



Orders over $75.00
Standard shipping $0.00


Rates for Canada:

Any size order
Standard shipping $13.88


Rates for any other country:
Standard shipping $23.88
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any plugin with this functionality, but it is customizable, a table can be created for each zone and rates table can be defined for order subtotal range.

Comment: Kindly, this was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, **a comment,** another question, or deleted altogether.